# Golang Logger polymorphism?

Tags: go

We use a third party library which accepts `*log.Logger` (stdlib Logger) as a parameter in its New function, but we implement `Logger` by ourself. It has the same "interface" with stdlib Logger.

Is there any hack way to pass our own implementation of Logger to the third library excepting asking the library owner to change the parameter type to interface？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If their package takes an actual *log.Logger, there's nothing you can do to inject your own logger other than set the output of a log.Logger to a custom writer where you intercept their log statements and you then re-log them through yours.

But that will be sub-awesome as you'd basically be parsing all their log statements just so you can re-log.   Not sure if log.Logger writes a log message as one call to Write.  if it does, it's easy as all you do is re-log for every call to Write.

You might also want to consider finding another library or forking and changing that library as nothing should really depend on log.Logger like that.